# First passage time distribution in birth-death processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, matlab, birth-death-process

I'm working on the following birth-death process $$X\rightleftharpoons A$$ in which the birth and death (transition) rates  are $t^+=k_2a$ and $t^-=k_1n$ respectively. $n$   is the concentration of $X$ and $a$ is a constant concentration of $A$.

I wrote down a continuous time Monte Carlo code in MATLAB that shows the number of particles as a function of time, $n(t)$. What I'm trying to do now is find the first passage time distribution to get to $n=0$ starting from some initial number of particles $n(0)=N$ and I'm not sure on how to do this.

What I tried doing is the following: I ran the program for many different realizations and in each realization I found the time at which $n=0$ for the first time and saved this realization and time. I was hoping I could extract some information from this on the distribution but I don't know how to continue on from here. I don't know if it's even the right approach to this question...

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the birth-death process more simply, without the words "concentration" and "$X$" and "$A$"? These things are not standard.   I would understand $N(t)$ is the number of objects in a birth-death chain.   Is $N(t)$ a continuous time Markov chain? (if so, what are the transition rates?)  Discrete time?  (if so, what are the transition probabilities?)

Comment: Hey Michael and thanks for the reply. I edited my post and hopefully it's more understandable now. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Is this a Markov chain?  What is the state space? What is $X$?  What is $A$? Why do you write $t^+$ and $t^-$?  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process

Comment: I assume I have molecules $X$ whose number is $n(t)$. Those Xs are created with rate $k_2$ and die with rate $k_1$. $A$  is assumed to be so abundant that its amount $a$ is practically constant.  The $X$ die or are born one at a time. So there are two processes that can occur: $n$ grows to $n+1$ or decreases to $n-1$. $t^+$ and $t^-$ are the transition rates. So, based on the reaction I wrote and its assumption, they are $k_2 a$ and $k_1 n$ respectively. I write them to use them in the Master equation. The state space takes natural numbers only.

Comment: So you have a population, $X_t$ that increase by $1$ at a rate of $t^+$ and decreases by $1$ at a rate of $t^-$. The birthrate is some constant, while the death rate is proportional to the current population size. So you have yourself a fairly standard queue and you're asking for the (distribution of the) extinction time $T^0=\inf\{t>0: X_t=0\}$? Do I have everything correct here?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes, I believe you are correct. I start from some initial state $n(0)=N$ and I am looking for the probability distribution that it takes time $t$  to reach $n=0$ for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_t$ denote a continuous time Markov chain on state space $\mathbb{Z}_+:=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ and transitions $n\to n+1$ at rate $\lambda$ and $n\to n-1$ at rate $\mu n$. That is $q_{n n+1}=\lambda$, $q_{nn-1}=n\mu$, where $q_{ij}$ are the entries of the transition rate matrix, $Q$ and assume $X_0=N$ a.s. Note, the average holding time in state $i\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ is $1/q_i$ where $q_i:=-q_{ii}=-(\lambda+i\mu)$. We also assume $0$ is an absorption state, so that once we enter that state we cannot leave (no births occur at zero population). Please indulge me in the change of notation.

Now set $T^j=\inf\{t>0 : X_t=j\}$, the hitting or passage time of state $j$. Then the time of extinction is just $T^0$ (here subscripts are not powers, of course). A first step to extract some information about the distribution is to compute the mean extinction time first. As the standard theory goes, we can compute $\mathbb{E}(T^0)$ by first computing $k_j:=\mathbb{E}_j(T^0):=\mathbb{E}(T^0 | X_0=j)$ for every positive integer $j$. In principle we can always compute $k_j$ by solving the corresponding difference equation:
$$k_j=\frac{1}{j\mu+\lambda}+\frac{\lambda}{j\mu+\lambda} k_{j+1}+\frac{j\mu}{j\mu+\lambda} k_{j-1},$$
with "boundary" condition $k_0=0$.
All of this and more is covered in J.R. Norris' *Markov Chains*. Of course, as I said this is just for computing the mean hitting time of a given state. The distribution is another beast but is obtainable sometimes. It is actually not too difficult to instead compute $\mathbb{P}(X_t=0)$ in some cases. For example when both rates are proportional to the population level and the initial population is $1$, i.e. $q_{n n+1}=n\lambda$, $q_{nn-1}=n\mu$, $X_0=1$, then one finds
$$\mathbb{P}(X_t=0)=\frac{\mu(e^{\mu t}-e^{\lambda t})}{\mu e^{\mu t}-\lambda e^{\lambda t}},$$
for any given time $t\geq 0$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the extensive explanation. To be honest, I am more concerned with how I to find the distribution numerically (I want to find the distribution, its mean and variance) rather than analytically.

Comment: Recurrence equations can undoubtedly be solved numerically, under some stability conditions—so there's a way to compute the mean extinction time without Monte-Carlo simulations of the entire process. But such numerical methods ought to be a new question entirely, if you're interested in that route. You could then compare this solution to the estimate obtained from simulating the process and averaging the realized extinction times. Though, note that a dominating birth rate can make the extinction chance very low and thus the realized extinction times very long.

Comment: I'm really only interested in how to obtain the distribution from my KMC simulation. Like I said above, I thought I could maybe gain some information about it if I run it for many different realizations and collect the times of extinction in every realization and organize them from smallest to largest, but I don't know how to assign a probability for this..

Comment: @FlyGuy Well you can always simulate the process and count how many times $T^0=t$ over a large set of $N$ simulations, and call this $N_t$. Then $\hat{p}=N_t/N$ is an estimate of $\mathbb{P}(T^0=t)$. Repeat for all $t$ (one must discretize time, of course). This is just an empirical probability estimate and its accuracy will depend on the number of simulations and behavior of the chain with respect to the relationship of the transition rates.

Comment: @FlyGuy more precisely, you should count the occurrences of $\{T^0 \leq t\}$ since you are dealing with continuous time.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. So you're suggesting to do the following: (1) Run a simulation for $n(t)$ . (2) Find the extinction time (call it $t^*$). (3) Repeat (1) and (2) for many simulations. (4) Basically I now have a vector of extinction times (a vector of $t^*$) for all the different runs. For each element of the vector, I start checking and counting how many are smaller or equal to it and divide that number by the total number of simulations?

Comment: @FlyGuy precisely but you should discretize some interval $A=[0,T]$ as $A_N=\{0, T/N, 2T/N,...,T\}$ and count how many realized extinction times are $\leq t_i\in A_N$ with $t_i=iT/N$ for $i=0,...,N$ rather than count how many realized extinction times are less than a fixed realized extinction time otherwise you may not be covering the time-space sufficiently—you can choose $T$ as the maximum realized time and $N$ large enough to get a decent grid approximation to $A$.

Comment: I think I understand what I need to do now. I'll try this and update. Thanks for all the help LoveTooNap29!

Comment: Coming to think of it, wouldn't I just get a growing number of counts for each $t_i$ that I check? Take for example $t_i=T$ where I assume $T$ is the maximum realized extinction time. wouldn't all extinction times be smaller than it and thus the count is basically $N$?

Comment: @FlyGuy yes, that is how an empirical CDF behaves, in emulation of theoretical CDFs. You said you wanted probabilities—since $T^0$ is a continuous RV (given this continuous time MC) you can directly estimate probabilities $\mathbb{P}(T^0\leq t)\approx |\{T^0\leq t\}|/N$ for $t\geq 0$. Remember that all CDFs tend to $1$ as the input (here $t$) grows, and for *all continuous* RVs, $\mathbb{P}(T^0=t)=0$ so one cannot estimate the probability events of equality, you must work with intervals. Indeed it is zero chance you will see e.g. $T^0=2.224719294$ but non zero chance for $2.22<T^0<2.23$.

Comment: Thanks for all the extensive explanations and reminders of probability (I'm a bit rusty with this). I apologize if I haven't stated this more clearly but I'm more interested in the probability distribution (PDF) rather than the CDF. However, I assume I can arrive at the PDF from the CDF through taking the (numerical) derivative of the CDF I now have, correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @FlyGuy PDF stands for *probability density function* while CDF stands for *cumulative distribution function* which is *also* referred to as the *probability distribution* of the relevant RV. A google (or perusal of wikipedia pages) of the terms will validate this standard terminology is indeed correct. You have correctly recalled that the PDF is the derivative of the CDF. For *all continuous RVs* the PDF, i.e the density, is *not* a probability, it may be that $f(x)>1$, while CDFs are true probabilities. For discrete RVs densities are called masses (PMF) and indeed *are valid probabilities*.

Comment: @FlyGuy to be clear: PDFs represent probabilities per unit—exactly why they are called probability densities! And informally $f(x)dx\approx \mathbb{P}(x < X\leq x+dx)$.

Comment: @FlyGuy at this point I would definitely encourage you to review any material you have on probability. It is a tremendous endeavor to estimate either the CDF or PDF of an RV when there is some confusion about the two notions and undoubtedly an example of “cart before the horse”.

Comment: Undoubtedly, I'm so rusty with this that I'm even confusing acronyms. In any case, thanks for all the help you've provided me so far!